# Delete or ignore rows that have empty tables when using Table.ExpandTableColumn | Power Query

Tags: error-handling, powerbi, powerquery

I need to expand a table column but some of the table contents are empty and return ""
when I run the query it stops at the first table where the content is empty.

I need to ignore these rows when using the Table.ExpandTableColumn or delete them beforehand.

```
#"Função Personalizada Invocada" = Table.AddColumn(#"Tipo Alterado", "generation_24hrs", each get_generation_24([user.data.id])),
#"generation_24hrs Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Função Personalizada Invocada", "generation_24hrs", {"entry.value.id", "entry.value.kwh_ger", "entry.value.kwh_con"}, {"entry.value.id", "entry.value.kwh_ger", "entry.value.kwh_con"})
```

Before

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
#"Função Personalizada Invocada" = Table.AddColumn(#"Tipo Alterado", "generation_24hrs", each get_generation_24([user.data.id])),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Função Personalizada Invocada", "RowCount", each Table.RowCount([generation_24hrs])),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([RowCount] <> "0")),
#"generation_24hrs Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "generation_24hrs", {"entry.value.id", "entry.value.kwh_ger", "entry.value.kwh_con"}, {"entry.value.id", "entry.value.kwh_ger", "entry.value.kwh_con"})
```

Comment: Thanks, the idea o of the row count resulted in a column with error values, but it was enough for me to remove the rows that were causing the problems